# How to create a batch script that deletes files older than X and not delete at the root folder and exclude certain subfolders?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

UPDATE: I figured out this and the answer is below :-)

How to create a batch script that deletes files older than X and not delete in the root folder and exclude certain subfolders?

So far I have this but it deletes files in the root in `C:\Temp\TestFolder\` and I only want it to delete files in the subdirectories. I also want to exclude certain subdirectories which I know I can put in an `exclude.txt` file but I'm not sure what the code would be to do this.

Current batch script:

```
echo deleting files...
forfiles /p C:\Temp\TestFolder\ /s /m *.* /D -30 /c "cmd /c echo /f /q @path"
echo finished deleting files!
pause
```

Comment: Just to let you know, if you haven't already seen the usage information for the `del` command, or understood how the `forfiles` utility works, that you definitely do not need to use the `/q` option. That option is only used when deleting multiple files, however your command would be deleting one file at a time. _You could potentially also use the `/a` option with `/f` however_. Also, you really do not currently have any idea whether all of the files were successfully deleted, so unless you incorporate a method to determine whether they all have been, you shouldn't be notifying that they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an untested example for you to run, play around with, and try to understand. *Just replace your source directory, and the names of your excluded directories as necessary, (note the doublequotes enclosing `My Files`, as it uses spaces/poison characters).*

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "source=C:\Temp\TestFolder"
Set "xclude="My Files" Backups"
For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%source%" "%source%"^
 /IS /L /MinAge:30 /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /S /XD %xclude% ^| ^
 %__AppDir__%\findstr.exe /VRI "%source:\=[\\]%[\\][^\\]*$"'
) Do Del /A /F "%%G"
```

*As you did not make a reasonable attempt at the task you'd laid out within your question, I will not be providing an explanation, or post support.*

Comment: btw @Compo - I DID make a reasonable attempt at the task... that was rude!

Comment: @DonnaLynn, your code did not attempt to exclude the root directory, or any additional directories. It used unnecessary `/m` and `/q` options, and did not limit the results from `forfiles.exe` to files only, e.g. _(`If @IsDir==FALSE`)_. Regardless of your opinion on the matter, I would not call that a reasonable attempt at the task you'd laid out.

Comment: OMGosh @Compo... what is the problem, why are you being rude? All this and I actually thanked you for your input. Just because I didn't go into detail about all the pains of not finding any solutions for my specific issue doesn't mean I didn't make a reasonable attempt. I did try isDir but that did not yield what I needed also /q option I wasn't sure about and at the time.  Exactly my point... I didn't know how to exclude and then specifically include. If I knew what to do I wouldn't have asked for help. BTW my solution is lickety-split fast and works perfectly for what we need. Just be nicer.

Comment: @DonnaLynn, please don't expect us to guess how much effort you have made. We can only base our responses on the information you provide in your question. At the time I answered, and even up to the time I started typing this response, you have not provided that information in your question. I have no doubt, especially based upon your now posted answer, that you had in fact made more effort than you'd clearly shown in your question. I applaud you for your effort in achieving your goal, but that does not excuse you for your lack of question quality or clairty.

Comment: I thoroughly tested my attempt and yours.  Yours won out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just finished the code (maby it will still help you.)

The powershell code is:

```
# pre-sets
$place = "C:\test"
$exclude_name = "C:\test\exclude.txt"
$wipe_list = "C:\test\wipe_list.txt"
$time = 5

#go to the root
cd $place

#get a list of alll folders in the root
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory

#get the excluded files
$exclude = get-content $exclude_name

#take the first line of the list of folders
ForEach ($line in $($folders -split "`r`n")){
    #go threw each line in the list of excluded items
    ForEach ($linex in $($exclude -split "`r`n")) {
    #if it finds a file in the directory that isnt equal to a exclusion file it will write it to $wipe_list
    if ("$line" -ne "$linex") {
        $line | Out-File -filepath $wipe_list -append
    }
}}
#clearing some variables
$exclude_nama = ""
$folders = ""
$exclude = ""
$line = ""
$linex = ""
#setting folders equal to all the folders to check and wipe
$folders = get-content $wipe_list
#read the list of folders 1 by 1
ForEach ($line in $($folders -split "`r`n")){
#go to the root
cd $place
#go to the sub folder
cd $line
#make a list of all files
$folder_list = dir
#split the list into single files
ForEach ($linex in $($folder_list -split "`r`n")){
#check how old the file is
$lastWrite = (get-item "$linex").LastWriteTime
$timespan = new-timespan -days $time 
if (((get-date) - $lastWrite) -gt $timespan) {
#delete the file if its older than $time
Remove-Item –path "$linex" –recurse -force
}
}
}
#clearing more variables
$time = ""
$timespan = ""
$linex = ""
$place = ""
$line = ""
$folders = ""
$folder_list = ""
#deleting the temp file
Remove-Item –path "$wipe_list"
#clearing the last variable
$wipe_list = ""
#closing the window
exit
```

The batch file code is:

```
@echo off
echo Starting ...
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\test\check_and_wipe.ps1'"
echo Done...
ping localhost >nul
exit
```

Looking at your code its the better option most likely
but if you want to use this replace the presets and the file path in the batch script.

Comment: Thanks.  It needs to be a batch file, not powershell.

Comment: Okay its very late rn so i will catch some sleep and work on the code in like 8.30 hours. Not that my sleep schedual could give 2 shits

Comment: Can it be a batch file that runs powershell.exe? If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. If you cannot run another .exe file, then `forfiles.exe` is also out.

Comment: @lit Not using powershell can have a lot of reasons like wanting to add it to a larger script. So it shouldnt matter to us.

Comment: @Donna Lynn  Does the root folder have other files or is it just the subs and the exclude.txt file? Also can you provide a basic model for me to test on (Only need the stuff that might be in the folders lile files and subs)

Comment: @smvd - What does "adding it to a larger script" have to do with anything. If the code works, then it works.

Comment: Can it be a batch file that runs powershell.exe? - I was just told it needed to be a batch file to be run via scheduled job.

Comment: The root folder will have other files.  It will have pdfs and txt files. My client just need to clean up folders of old pdf and text files to be run every night and requested a batch file.

Comment: I will see what i can cookup with the rule to start from a batch script.

Comment: So i need to enter any non chosen sub folders and wipe their content?

Comment: Need to delete only the files from only sub folders (not the root) and we need to exclude some sub folders (using i.e. exclude.txt file)

Comment: Ok i will add the code in like 8/9 hours gotta sleep now

Comment: @smvd Thank you for your support. Hope you had a good nights rest.

Comment: Thank you @smvd!  I might put it to go use soon.  Thank you so much for your kindness and help!  You are what this site is about.  I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

Update(1/8/2021): This didn't work 2 subdirectories deep. :(

YAY!  I figured it out myself!

Thank you @smvd for your time!  btw @Compo I can't use robocopy - my client is running out of space and that would cause an issue right now.  But thank you!

```
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "C:\Temp\TestFolder\" ^| findstr /I /V /L /G:"C:\Temp\TestFolder\exclude.txt"') DO (
    forfiles /p %%D /D -30 /c "cmd /c del @file" >nul 2>nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO No %%D files 30 days old or older were found.
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%D files as old as 30 days or older have been deleted.
    )
)
```

Comment: There was nothing in your question about not being able to use robocopy.exe, which is already part of your OS, and therefore should not be an issue. My answer at the time of posting, does not use `powershell.exe`, which was stated in the comments, and as such fulfilled the question. _Using `forfiles.exe` is also one heck of a lot slower than my method too_.

Comment: Normally robocopy.exe would work but the client is running out of disk space.  So for now the script I wrote will work.  I will probably rewrite after this emergency script is run. I'll want to eventually write something to also log the files that were deleted too.  For now, I have something my client will be happy with to clean up their drive for the ASAP ticket that this is.

Comment: Could you please explain your "running out of diskspace" comment. Just rereading this back, I feel you're implying that Robocopy.exe is using diskspace. If that's what you mean, as nothing is being copied, only listed, _(`/L`)_, and the source and destination are exactly the same too, I'm not sure how that would be.